# Preserving Form hierarchy when importing form into another project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I want to use the form of another VB.NET project in a new project.

When I insert it as "Import existing element" and choose the form's ".vb" file, only the .vb file is imported into the new project.

When I add all three files (.vb, .Designer, and .resx), they are imported individually. The form hierarchy breaks, and VS2017 doesn't recognize it as a form with the sub-elements .res and .designer anymore.

Copying all three files into the new project's folder doesn't help either.

How can I preserve the form hierarchy?

That's how it looks:
[image]

Comment: It is called file nesting. You can use this extension to repair your solution without messing directly with the vbprj file https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting However let me say that this should not happen if you import first the frmMain.vb.

Comment: I'm not sure where this "Import existing element" option is but I would be right-clicking the project in the Solution Explorer and selecting 'Add' > 'Existing item'. Is that what you actually meant? If not, give that a try and see if it works as desired.

Comment: Try to exclude them from the project and include them again. It will be fixed automatically.